# Can I use Redis strictly as a referenced assembly, compiled within my application?

Tags: .net, redis

I have a project that I'd like to use Redis with as an in-memory database that caches the database to disk.  From all information I've gathered, it seems that Redis would be a great choice for my needs.  The one issue is that it seems that before you can use Redis, you have to install it on your machine.

Can Redis be added to a .Net solution as a library and compiled as part of my single installation package, rather than as a separate application/service that must be installed on a users machine?

Basically, I'd like to use this like a localized database similar to SqlLite/Sql Server CE except with all of the features of Redis.  Can this be done?

I suspect the answer is no but, if it isn't, how can I create a local database from within my project and open/close it from within my application?  I can't find a straight answer on if this is possible or not and, if so, how to do it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Local database as in SQL Local DB?

Comment: Yes.  I mean, I pass in a file name to store the database, and it works with that file as the cached data file source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are talking about the [Windows port of Redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis). No you can not do this. In a Windows environment - Redis can run either as an app or a Windows Service. It is meant to be installed on a server and serve as a distributed cache / NoSQL database. If you do decide to use redis, I recommend using the [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) client.

If you are looking to have a local cache, then you can use the [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx). Another option is to use [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx). Neither of them have the same features of Redis.